# Rails scope NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app with a table called workorders.  I'm trying to create 2 index lists.  One with open workorders and one with closed workorders.  Closed workorders have a wostatus_id = 231

I'm trying to use a scope for this.  This is in my workorder model:

```
  scope :closed, where(":wostatus_id = ?", 231 )
  scope :notclosed, where("wostatus_id != ?", 231 )
```

In one view, I have:

```
  <% @workorders.closed.each do |workorder| %>
```

But, I get the following error:

```
undefined method 'closed'for #>Array.....
```

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Show us code, where @workorders assigned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have something like `@workorders = Workorder.all` in your controller, this returns Array, not relation

Instead you need something like `@workorders = Workorder.scoped`, which returns relation that can be chained with another scopes.

Comment: I would second this. @workorders is an instance variable; you need to call it on the class itself.

Comment: Does this do something similar.  (a scope worked on this one).       @worequests = Worequest.order(:created_at)